# replace and imputing missing data in time series

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time-series, missing-data

I have time series data with missing values in some date and time
I want to have a imputing  method taking into account the days for example if Monday at 1pm I have a missing data I will replace it with the same recording (data) from last Monday at the same time.

if someone can help me i will be grateful here is an excerpt from the data format i have:

```
date                        total   hour
2021-02-09 10:00:00         102.0   10
2021-02-09 11:00:00         175.0   11
2021-02-09 12:00:00         234.0   12
2021-02-09 13:00:00         272.0   13
2021-02-09 14:00:00         117.0   14
2021-02-09 15:00:00         300.0   15
2021-02-10 10:00:00                 10
2021-02-10 11:00:00         200.0   11
```

Comment: your example shows no missing data? also, what language?

Comment: yes I only show an extract of the data and it's python

Comment: I mean it might be good if your example *included* missing data, essentially making a [mre]. Also, you might want to add something you tried to solve this.

Comment: I have modified the example

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the current value with the one of last Monday:

```
curTime="2021-02-10 10:00:00"
curIndex = df["date"]==curTime
df.loc[curIndex] = df.loc[curIndex].replace(np.nan, prevValue)
```

Besides, I'd like to introduce some methods for you:

1. **pandas**, `fillna` function. You can use method="ffill" or "bfill" or combine them. Time series are more suitable for backward/forward imputation than general data.
2. [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gettingstarted.html), a famous package designed for time series. There are many classical methods to analysis time series.